# React Native Build failing randomly

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

My project was working fine last time I checked. However, I am unable to build it now and I don't think I changed anything in my project. This is the error message

```
What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle3330051715056052591.bin offset 88368 exists? true
```

I looked at similar questions on StackOverflow and couldn't find anything useful except that this happens randomly.
A few days ago the build started failing (something about mergeDexDebug) randomly and restarting the computer somehow fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to build successfully by changing firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" to firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" in android/build.gradle but I still don't understand how this was working all along and stopped today.